# Create 2 Models at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

Ok I've searched far and wide and can't find a solution that I can get working...so I decided to post here.

I have 2 models

**Store**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :storeimage, :storename
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true  
end
```

and

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :userimage, :remove_userimage
  has_secure_password
  has_many :gears
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_one :store, :dependent => :destroy
  before_save :create_remember_token
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :userimage, UserpicUploader
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store

  ...

end
```

When someone creates a new user account I need to automatically create a new store for that user I was thinking within the user form. So how can I create a new store object that's linked to the new user being created?

Here is my code from the **User Controller for CreateAction**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, :flash => {:success => "Welcome to Equiptme"}
    else
      render 'new'
      @title = "Sign up"
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<div class="signup_container">
    <div class="signup_container_interior">
    <%= provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div>
        <div>
          The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
        </div>
        <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
      <div class="register_field">  
        <div class="register_nonerror_container">
            <%= f.label :first_name %>&nbsp;<%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'register_text_area' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="register_field">
        <div class="register_nonerror_container">
            <%= f.label :last_name %>&nbsp;<%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'register_text_area' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="register_field">
        <div class="register_nonerror_container">
            <%= f.label :email %>&nbsp;<%= f.text_field :email, class: 'register_text_area' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!--************STORE FIELDS ************** -->

    <!--************STORE FIELDS END ************** --> 

      <div class="register_field">
        <div class="register_nonerror_container">
            <%= f.label :password %>&nbsp;<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'register_text_area' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="register_field">
        <div class="register_nonerror_container">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>&nbsp;<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'register_text_area' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: 'register_button' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why didn't you use `after_save` callback with `new_record?`method?

Comment: Did you search on the [rails association docs page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`build_association` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) created along with the `has_one` relationship between users and stores:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.build_store

  # etc
end
```

If you don't need the store until you've saved the user, you might also use `create_association`:

```
  if @user.save
    @user.create_store
    # etc
  end
```

Comment: I decided to use the create_association. How do I pass a parameter like :storename?

Comment: Just as if you were calling create: `@user.create_store(:storename => 'House of Pancakes')`

Comment: Thank You..I think I understood that part. I wasn't sure how to pass the Store parameter in the User form. I've posted my view. I was trying to use the method posted on the railscasts updated episode on nested forms, but It wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I saw this episode but I couldn't get it to work for creating vs updating. Thanks Anyways.